# array return a String and not an Object

Tags: java

Hello i have to make a program first i ask for code for log in i put a `try/catch` because I want the password is only numbers if give a character to stimulates the exception
and the secont is not show a n array of the objects `Product` but an a string `Productl@pos51sd` and i cant find why show me this.

```
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RMIClient {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                int pin=0;
        try {   

            String  name    =   "//Localhost/RMI_Server";
            Functions lp    =(Functions)Naming.lookup(name);
            try{
            System.out.println("Please give your Personal Code (PIN)");

                        pin=in.nextInt();
             }catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    System.out.println("Input must be a number.");
                            }
            if(lp.validate(pin)){
            System.out.println("Give description of item");
            String desc=in.next();
                        int sizep=lp.search(desc).length;
                        Product [] p =new Product[sizep];
                        System.arraycopy(lp.search(desc),0,p,0,sizep);
                        for(int i=0;i<sizep;i++){
            System.out.println(p[i].toString());}
            System.out.println("Give numberCode of item you want to buy");
            String code=in.next();
            System.out.println(lp.purchase(code));
            }else{
            System.out.println("Your code is False");}
            lp.close();
        }catch (Exception   e)  {
             System.out.println("SumClient  err:    " + e); 
             System.exit(1);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact output you're receiving

Answer (score 0):

it prints the result of the toString() method.

You can find some details about printing exceptions on System.out. in java here http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-exception-printing-log4j

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have not showed us the class `Product` but what you actually want to do is to implement method `toString()` in this class according to your requirements. I do not know what `pos51sd` is but just for the discussion let's call variable that contains this value `code`.

In this case your class `Product` should look like:

```
class Product {
    .....
    private String code;
    .......

    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + "@" + code;
    }
}
```

Comment: in product toString the code is
'public String toSting(){
  return "Item "+ serialNum +" is product from "+ company +" price " + price +"E Description: ( "+ description +" )";
  
 }'

Answer (score 0):

the class Product 'import java.io.Serializable;

public class Product implements Serializable {

```
private String description;
private String serialNum;
private float price;
private String company;

public Product(String description,String serialNum,float price,String company){
this.description=description;
this.serialNum=serialNum;
this.price=price;
this.company=company;       
}

public void set_description(String description){this.description=description;}
public String get_description(){return description;}
public void set_serialNum(String serialNum){this.serialNum=serialNum;}
public String get_serialNum(){return serialNum;}
public void set_price(float price){this.price=price;}
public float get_price(){return price;}
public void set_company(String company){this.company=company;}
public String get_company(){return company;}



public String toSting(){
    return "Item "+ serialNum +" is product from "+ company +" price " + price +"E Description: ( "+ description +" )";

}
```

}
'

Comment: i change toString 'return getClass().getName() + "Item "+ serialNum +" is product from "+ company +" price " + price +"E Description: ( "+ description +" )";' but i have the same problem